# Disable creation of scroll-content in Ionic 2 app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

In my `<ion-content>` element the ionic automatically creates a `scroll-content` child. How to disable this?

Comment: Any problem with that?

Comment: I don't need this element. It adds a top padding. It would be possible to override this padding with 0 but that's not a clean solutions I think.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a pretty ugly workarund would be to add a style rule like

```
scroll-content {
    padding-top: 0px !important;
}
```

I've checked the documentation, but I can not find how to prevent that `<scroll-content>` element from being created.

Answer (score 0):

I do had the same problem. Try the following code.

```
.helllot >.scroll-content {
          padding: 0px !important;
          }
```

html

```
<ion-scroll scrollX="true" style="height:54px;" class="helllot">
   <ion-row>
        <ion-col width-25>
            hello1
        </ion-col> 
        <ion-col width-25>
            hello1
        </ion-col> 
   </ion-row>
  </ion-scroll>
```